# casting an object after getclass() method

Tags: java, casting

I have a mouse event on a swing component that can be of 2 different custom classes: ModelTable & Modelcompte which are swing components created with netbeans swing gui and they both extends JPanel.they share some methods and attributes.

```
Component source = (Component) evt.getSource();
Component panel = (Component) (source.getParent()
                                     .getParent()
                                     .getParent()
                                     .getParent()
                                     .getParent());
Class clazz = panel.getClass();
clazz.cast(panel);
```

When I print the class of panel it gives me the right Class but when I try to use method of that class on panel it can't find the method ("method ... in class Component doesn't exist"). Seems that panel is still of Class Component...

what I want to do is:

```
if (panel instance of ModelTable){
    panel.setQuantity(1);
}
else if (panel instance of ModelCompte){
    panel.setQuantity(2)
}
```

Thanks for your help!

```
// and by the way I don't know why I can't directly do this : 
(Component) panel = (Component) (evt.getsource()
                                    .getParent()
                                    .getParent()
                                    .getParent()
                                    .getParent()
                                    .getParent());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask a single question per post - your second "by the way" question should be in a separate post, with more detail - you haven't said what happens when you *try* to do that. (Note that you have a typo though - `getsource` should be `getSource()`.

Comment: Note that if you're using `instanceof` anyway, you could just cast within the `if` statement: `((ModelTable) panel).setQuantity(1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Seems that panel is still of Class Component...

Yes. You're performing the cast, but not doing anything with the result. It doesn't change the compile-time type of the `panel` variable.

If you know which method you want to call, presumably you know at least *some* type that it's declared in - so cast to that type using the normal non-reflection code:

```
Component source = (Component) evt.getSource();
MyPanel panel = (MyPanel) source.getParent()
                                .getParent()
                                .getParent()
                                .getParent()
                                .getParent();
```

If you've got the same method declared in multiple classes, you could either give them a common superclass with that method, or make them implement an interface declaring that method. You'd then cast to the superclass or interface, at which point you can call the method. (It's hard to be more concrete in the answer without a concrete example in the question.)

Comment: that's the point of my question, the type of panel can be of 2  custom Classes (ModelTable and ModelCompte) so I can't do what you're suggesting.

Comment: @marui: And they both contain the same method signature, and that's the method you want to call? (None of this information is in your question.) If that's the case, you should make them inherit from a common superclass, possibly abstract, that contains the method. Then you can cast to that superclass.

Comment: yes they basically contain the same methods but they are Component created with netbeans swing gui so they already extend a class(JPanel). an interface then?

Comment: problem is I have a test on panel's Class (if panel instance of ...) so I really need to cast panel into the right class

Comment: @marui: It's unclear *why* you're using `instanceof`. It sounds like there's an awful lot of context that you haven't provided in the question, which makes it much harder to help you. Note that if the panel already extends a class, you'd just make the intermediate abstract class extent `JPanel` instead, so that the type hierarchy is preserved.